# About the equivalence of two definitions of right Kan extension

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $I$, $J$ be two small categories and $f: I\to J$ be a functor. By composition with $f$, we have  a functor $f^*: \textrm{Pr(J)}\to \textrm{Pr(I)}$, where $\textrm{Pr(-)}=Fun((-)^{op},\mathbb{Set})$ is category of presheaves. The functor $f^*$ has a right adjoint $f_*$, which is called the right Kan extension. There are two ways to define $f_*$ as follows:

**Definition 1.** Since a right adjoint of $f^*$ is equivalent to a left Kan extension of the identity functor $1_{\textrm{Pr}(J)}: \textrm{Pr}(J)\to \textrm{Pr(J)}$ along $f^*$ which is preserved by $f^*$. We can define $f_*=Lan_{f^*}1_{\textrm{Pr}(J)}$. And by the colimit construction of left Kan extension, we have:
$$
f_*(F)=\textrm{colim}~G,
$$
where the colimit is taken over $f^*G\to F$ (the comma category).

**Definition 2.** It is also well-known that we can define $f_*(F)$ to be the right Kan extension of $F: I^{op}\to \mathbb{Set}$ along $f: I^{op}\to J^{op}$. That is $f_*(F)=Ran_f F$. Also by the limit construction of right Kan extension. We have:
$$
f_*(F)(j)=\lim F(i),
$$
where the limit is taken over $f(i)\to j$ ($\to$ is a morphism in $J$).

My question is how to prove the above two definitions are equivalent. More concretely, why we should have:
$$
\textrm{colim}~G(j)\cong \lim F(i).
$$

**Remark:** Since for any $f^*G\to F, f(i)\to j$ we have the following composition:
$$
G(j)\to G(f(i))=f^*G(i)\to F(i),
$$
it is easy to construct a natural map from $\textrm{colim}~G(j)$ to $\lim F(i)$. But it is not clear to me why this natural map is an isomorphism.

Comment: Of course ,this follows immediately from the uniqueness of the right adjoint. But I still want a direct proof in this particular example.